# How to convert the string to date time format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strip

I have the following string 20211208_104755, representing date_time format. I want to convert it to the python datetime format using datetime.strip() method.

```
mydatetime = "20211208_104755"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(mydatetime, '%y/%m/%d')
```

However I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: time data '20211208' does not match format '%y/%m/%d'
```

Comment: I don't understand - if you have string `mydatetime` without `/` then why you use `/` in `'%y/%m/%d'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument in strptime has to match the pattern of your datetime string. You can find the patterns and their meaning on https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

In your case, you can format it as

```
from datetime import datetime

mydatetime = "20211208_104755"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(mydatetime, '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')

print(datetime_object)


>>> 2021-12-08 10:47:55
```

Answer (score 1):

what should work is to define how the `mydatetime` string is composed.
example:
`%Y is the year (4 digits);` check [here](https://pynative.com/python-datetime-format-strftime/) for format (section strftime() Date Format Codes)

So in your example I would assume it's like this:

```
mydatetime = "20211208_104755"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(mydatetime, '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
print (datetime_object)
```

result

```
2021-12-08 10:47:55
```

and

```
type(datetime_object)
datetime.datetime
```